# How to remove fragment item in ArrayAdapter in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

We have a Array Adapter with fragment items.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(view == null){
        view = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        view.setId(View.generateViewId());
    }

    Fragment fragment = getItem(position);
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(view.getId(), fragment)
            .commit();

    return view;
}
```

We want to remove one item from list.When we remove last item of list it works well, but for removing a middle or first item in the list a error was occurred.

We know the problem is in replace method, it gets wrong id!!!
The removing item code is this:

```
int count = mAdapter.getCount();
for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    Fragment fragment = mAdapter.getItem(i);
    if (fragment.getClass().equals(aClass)) {
        mAdapter.remove(fragment);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment ScheduleD{b3087758 #2 id=0xf}: was 15 now 14
```

Comment: post code where you are removing

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @tpA  I added the removing code,thx.

Comment: @Jörn Buitink I added the error,thx.